# How to get the amplitude in X and Y of an image in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine

I have an rectangular image in Google Earth Engine and I would like to know its height and width. How can I do that?

I tried this below, but the result was 0.0013635360788981643
0.5018710804225908 for X and Y, but the amplitude should be something bigger than 0, because I want to divide this image later into a bunch of images with shape 256x256

```
listaCoord = ee.List(geometria.coordinates().get(0))
t0 = listaCoord.get(1)

t1 = listaCoord.get(3)

x0 = t0.getInfo()[0]
y0 = t0.getInfo()[1]
x1 = t1.getInfo()[0]
y1 = t1.getInfo()[1]

ampX = (x1 - x0)

ampY = (y0 - y1)
```

Answer (score 1):

First off, remember every time you call `getInfo()` that is a round trip to the server. So, if you are calling it more than once to get an answer - there is likely a better way.

If I understand the question correctly, you are looking for the height and width of an image in pixels at the source resolution? If that is the case - this information is stored on the metadata for each band in the image. Bands can have different resolutions and projections, so the answer to your question may vary upon which band you are looking at. Using a Sentinel-2 L2A image, here is how to print that information out with one getInfo() call (these images are UTM projected, so resolution units are meters/pixel).

```js
var s2 = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2_SR");
var img = s2.first().getInfo();

img.bands.forEach(
  function(band, idx) {
    print(
      'band: ' + band.id,
      'x res: ' + band.crs_transform[0] + 'm/pixel',
      'y res: ' + band.crs_transform[4] + 'm/pixel',
      'dimensions: ' + 
        band.dimensions[0] + ' by ' + 
        band.dimensions[1] + ' pixels');

  }
);
```